# Modeling expansion in a pressurized cylinder

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, kinematics

> Consider a piston head in a arbitrarily long cylinder. One side of the
>   cylinder is sealed and pressurized, the other side has no pressure.
>   How would you model the acceleration or velocity of the piston head
>   with respect to time?

I began with the gas law $PV = P_0V_0$. P and V are instantaneous values wheras $P_0$ and $V_0$ are initial values, thus constants. I used the relations of $P = \frac{F}{A}$ and $F = ma$ to rewrite it in terms of acceleration.

$$a = \frac{P_0V_0A}{Vm} \rightarrow A = \frac{aVm}{P_0V_0}$$

Solving for $A$, area of the piston head, will come in handy in a bit. To model the changing volume I came up with this expression:

$$dV = A\ ds$$

$s$ is the displacement the piston head. Then I substituted the value of $A$ in the top equation into the lower one. (Note that you can use this same approach with $dt$ instead, but using $A$ was more straight forward. Both approaches gave me the same result in the end.)

$$dV = \frac{Vm}{P_0V_0}a\ ds$$

By definition, $a\ ds$ equals $v\ dv$ and with some other algebra, the equation can be rearranged to:

$$ \frac{dV}{V} = \frac{m}{P_0V_0}v\ dv$$

And finally integrate:

$$\int_{V_0}^{V}\frac{dV}{V}  = \int_{0}^{v} \frac{m}{P_0V_0}v\ dv$$

$$\ln{V} - ln{V_0} = \frac{m}{2P_0V_0}v^2 - 0$$

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{2P_0V_0}{m}\ln{\frac{V}{V_0}}}$$

I found a fallacy with this equation. At initial conditions, the acceleration is infinite. My intuition tells me the velocity should be asymptotic, but its logarithmic, and that the acceleration should be an exponential decay, but its inverse. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but it confuses me a little bit that you do everything from scratch. Can't we just write Newton's second law for piston? Start from introducing $x$ as a coordinate along the infinite axis of cylinder, write Newton's second law for it $m\ddot{x} = F_{\mathrm{pressure}}(x)$?

Comment: @Evgeny what is x dot? Anyway, I did use f=ma in the first step to convert the force into an acceleration... Am I not understanding something?

Comment: It's a second derivative of $x$ with respect to time $t$. I'll try to take another careful look at your equations.

Comment: I still recommend you to change the approach. Besides the strange behaviour of acceleration, your formula doesn't answer the question: you found the behaviour of velocity with respect to volume and you don't really know how volume changes in time. If you rewrite your equation using standard approach, you would get an equation $\ddot{x} = \frac{K}{x}$ which has no problem with acceleration except where it should have. You can fix some errors in your approach, but the result would be the same: the formula is not very useful for analysis.

Comment: @Ryan, As a starting point, see this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81038/math-physics-help-barrel-pressure-and-velocity